# FloatBuffer taking up more and more RAM

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

When I use FloatBuffers, they take up more and more memory over time. I use a float buffer to put a transormation matrix in it, and then I upload it to the shader. So I call the method, which creates the float buffer, every frame.

```
private static FloatBuffer matrixBuffer;

public void uploadUniformMatrix4f(String name, Matrix4f matrix4f)
{
    // Create a float buffer and put the matrix in it
    matrixBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    matrix4f.get(matrixBuffer);


    // Upload the float buffer as a matrix
    GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv(getUniformLocation(name), false, matrixBuffer);
}
```

I already tried `memFree(matrixBuffer);` and `matrixBuffer.clear();` but nothing worked.

[image: The first four slots are getting higher and higher]

Comment: `which creates the float buffer, every frame` sounds like you're hanging onto memory and not releasing it.  Run a profiler on your code to find out where this buffer is not being released.

Comment: @markspace I just used JProfiler (for the first time, actually) and found out that ByteBuffers and FloatBuffers are taking up more and more space. Also, when commenting out the shader upload thing, this doesn't happen. Do you know how to free up the space?

Comment: @httpdigest Thank you! :) Now, I instantly create the Buffer with BufferUtils and not every time the method is called. It works better, but the problem is still not fixed

Answer (score 2):

[BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16)](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/BufferUtils.html#createByteBuffer(int)) creates new buffer each time your are calling it, outside of JVM heap. I.e. java garbage collector only have reference to the ByteBuffer object, and not for it's data unlike an `float[] data = new float[16];` so GC will clear native memory at time it need to clear JVM heap.

BufferUtils approach is not recommended by [lwjgl](https://blog.lwjgl.org/memory-management-in-lwjgl-3/).

> LWJGL versions before 3 relied exclusively on allocateDirect(), via
>   the org.lwjgl.BufferUtils class. This class is still there in 3, for
>   backwards-compatibility, but its use is highly discouraged. The reason
>   is simple, allocateDirect() is horrible:

You can use following approach to transfer OpenGL matrices effectively.

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv;
......
try (MemoryStack stack = MemoryStack.stackPush()) {

   final FloatBuffer matrixBuffer = stack.mallocFloat(16);
   // if you have more matrices like mvp, model, view, projection, normal
   // you don't have to create new memory stack for them
   // simply call stack.mallocFloat(16) as many times as you need  
   matrix4f.get(matrixBuffer);

   glUniformMatrix4fv(getUniformLocation(name), false, matrixBuffer);
   // call OpenGL shader program code here. 
   // When this try block ends - matrixBuffer native memory will be invalid. And OpenGL will crash when accessing the uniform memory already freed   
}
```